# What is meant by “Study Track”?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application

I’ve been looking for master’s programmes on university websites for a while and a couple of times, I’ve come across “Study Track” written in front of the programmes like English Studies [Study Track]. I wonder if it has a specific meaning which distinguishes it from a programme!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What country? .

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- If you’re asking about the programme I talked about above, it’s offered at uni of Padua, Italy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the question more concrete, let us consider [an example](https://www.unipd.it/en/educational-offer/second-cycle-degree/human-and-social-sciences-and-cultural-heritage?tipo=LM&scuola=SU&key=8277&cg=humanities-and-literary-studies).
It seems that they are actually offering a [Master of Arts in European and American Languages and Literatures](https://apply.unipd.it/courses/course/178-english-studies), but this is far too broad a topic. So, they have predefined several "study tracks" to provide a thorough grounding in a more narrow topic (in this case, English Studies -- particularly, English language, linguistics, and literature).

Such "tracks" are also common in undergraduate degrees: for example, students earning a B.S. in Mathematics might be able to choose between tracks offering specialization in pure math, applied math, math education, or actuarial science.

Comment: "European and American Languages" is an enormous set of languages ... but they probably don't mean indigenous languages of the Americas ...

Comment: I had in mind exactly the same programme you provided as an example in your explanation :) So, as far as I understand, it actually means branch or sub-category, right?

Comment: @Azor They probably do include indigenous languages "in principle"; not much point in adding the qualifier "and American" if they only mean English, Spanish, French, and Portuguese. I agree it's highly unlikely they regularly offer courses in indigenous American languages though.

Comment: @HaniehMirhosseini - right. I would think of it as "focus area"; i.e., which part of this huge topic are you actually going to study. Not so unusual: for example, I have a PhD in Physics, but I certainly don't have expert knowledge of physics as a whole. I know almost nothing about superconductivity, for example.

Comment: @cag51 I see! I don’t know how to thank you! You were a great help to me. Thank you

Comment: @cag51 Tbf, there's more speakers of English, Spanish, and Portuguese in the Americas than in Europe, so maybe they're just trying to be pluricentric.